# PHP preg_replace YouTube Links

Tags: php, regex

Is it best to use preg_replace to add things to urls? Currently I am trying to get a youtube video and change replace it with the code [video] link [/video], for example using preg_replace:

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zgp_G5o6Oc
```

and changing it to

```
[video]www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zgp_G5o6Oc[/video]
```

So should I use `preg_replace()` or is there a better/easier method?

Comment: you can, but why don't use your parse_url/parse_str to do it for you?

Comment: if `$sptr = "www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zgp_G5o6Oc";` then only `$str = '[video]' . $str.'[video]';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the URL isolated in a variable, just do this:

```
$taggedUrl = sprintf("[video]%s[/video]", $url);
```

Or:

```
$taggedUrl = "[video]" . $url . "[/video]";
```

Or:

```
$taggedUrl = "[video]{$url}[/video]";
```

But, if you need to find the URL inside other text, `preg_replace()` would be appropriate:

```
preg_replace('/((?:https?:\/\/)?www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=\w+)/', '[video]\1[/video]', $inputString);
```

For example:

```
php > $inputString = "osme regewgqg affbefqeif rgqbig www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zgp_G5o6Oc sgwe\nhttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZrRpG_o6Oc wbqergq http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zgp_G5o6Oc   gegrqe";
php > var_dump($inputString);
string(176) "osme regewgqg affbefqeif rgqbig www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zgp_G5o6Oc sgwe
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZrRpG_o6Oc wbqergq http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zgp_G5o6Oc   gegrqe"

php > var_dump(preg_replace('/((?:https?:\/\/)?www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=\w+)/', '[video]\1[/video]', $inputString));
string(221) "osme regewgqg affbefqeif rgqbig [video]www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zgp_G5o6Oc[/video] sgwe
[video]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZrRpG_o6Oc[/video] wbqergq [video]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Zgp_G5o6Oc[/video]   gegrqe"
php >
```

To explain the regex used:

```
/.../    # Marks the start and end of the expression.
(...)    # Captures the entire match as \1
(?:...)? # ?: Makes a non-capturing group.
         # We put it in parenthesis to group this part of the expression.
         # The ? at the end makes the whole group optional
         # (so that http:// or https:// is not required at all, but matched if present)
https?   # Match either 'http' or 'https'.
\w+      # Matches one or more 'word characters' (0-9, a-z, A-Z, _)
```